# Django queryset and generator

Tags: python, django, iteration, generator

Just out of the blue I wonder if the following way of iterating through a result set using generator will cause any positive or negative impact against normal iteration?

eg.

```
def all_items_generator():
  for item in Item.objects.all():
    yield item

for item in all_items_generator():
  do_stuff_with_item(item)
```

against:

```
for item in Item.objects.all():
  do_stuff_with_item(item)
```

Comment: Why do the generator at all? It doesn't add anything.

Comment: Hi, that's why I am wondering if the generator will pose any performance/resource changes?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The former will be slower, since it will create a list containing all the models and then yield them one at a time, whereas the latter will just use the list directly. If you want  a generator then you should use [`QuerySet.iterator()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) instead.

Comment: Are you sure that calling `iterator` will yield results as they come, and not just avoid caching? It doesn't *specifically* say so in the documentation.

Comment: @NirIzr: What is the difference between those two things?

Comment: It could, for example, create a list of results and return that list.
I did now find this: http://blog.etianen.com/blog/2013/06/08/django-querysets/ which specifically says you're right.

Comment: But then they would be cached in the list.

Comment: I understand `caching` as saving the results for later queries. This is not a requirement as calling `.all()` might (without caching) trigger another DB-query. There's no need to over-discuss this, your answer was useful to me and I've upvoted it. Just wasn't clear on the part, IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

No. Other than the fact that it's more verbose, redundant, and not particularly useful (in the context of the generator you provided).

When you do `Item.objects.all()` in a `for`, they're iterated using [iterator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) with query caching ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L95)). If you don't want the results to be cached, use `iterator()` like Ignacio recommends.