# Create Generator from queryset results - Python?

Tags: django, generator, django-queryset, python-3.6

I am new to python I need to convert this following function to the generator to save memory, how can I achieve that?

```
question = <QuerySet [<Question: foobar?.>]>
for index, question in enumerate(questions):
        if question["pk"] == self.pk:
            try:
                next_question = questions[index + 1]
                if next_question["pk"]:
                    prev_next.update({"next" : next_question["pk"] })
            except IndexError:
                prev_next.update({"complete" : True })

            try:
                if index > 0:
                    previous_question = questions[index - 1]
                    if previous_question["pk"]:
                        prev_next.update({"prev" : previous_question["pk"] })
            except IndexError:
                pass

    return prev_next
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django queryset and generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292343/django-queryset-and-generator)

Comment: This is easily implemented with https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-next-prev/1.0.1 this package. And specifying an ordering on model options Model._meta.ordering = ['created_at']